# Rails ActiveSupport NoMethodError from unicode.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport, friendly-id

In my rails 3.2.15 project I'm getting inconsistent failures in my specs coming from `active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb`. Sometimes the specs fail, sometimes they pass. I haven't seen it outside of the tests, though. It's in the same particular area of the code each time. It seems to be the area where ActiveSupport is loading `unicode_tables.dat`. What's even more baffling is that if I go into ActiveSupport to the line in question and prepend it with `p` to output the values, it actually passes where it failed before and fails further on. FriendlyId is in the stack, so I'm wondering if that has anything to do with the problem. The line in my code that triggers the exception is just `update_attributes!(:pdf_processing => false)`. What am I missing?

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:350:in `load'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:335:in `codepoints'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:158:in `block in decompose_codepoints'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:147:in `each'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:147:in `inject'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:147:in `decompose_codepoints'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:291:in `normalize'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/inflector/transliterate.rb:62:in `transliterate'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/inflector/transliterate.rb:84:in `parameterize'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:155:in `parameterize'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/friendly_id-4.0.10.1/lib/friendly_id/slugged.rb:245:in `normalize_friendly_id'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/friendly_id-4.0.10.1/lib/friendly_id/slugged.rb:262:in `should_generate_new_friendly_id?'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/friendly_id-4.0.10.1/lib/friendly_id/slugged.rb:273:in `set_slug'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:407:in `_run__895003607475416689__validation__177331951454965097__callbacks'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activemodel-3.2.15/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:53:in `run_validations!'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activemodel-3.2.15/lib/active_model/validations.rb:195:in `valid?'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/validations.rb:69:in `valid?'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/validations.rb:77:in `perform_validations'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/validations.rb:56:in `save!'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:33:in `save!'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:264:in `block in save!'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:264:in `save!'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:228:in `block in update_attributes!'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:226:in `update_attributes!'
 # ./app/models/campaign.rb:291:in `ensure in generate_pdf'
 # ./app/models/campaign.rb:291:in `generate_pdf'
 # ./spec/models/campaign/generate_pdf_spec.rb:53:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:114:in `instance_eval'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:114:in `block in run'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:254:in `with_around_each_hooks'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:111:in `run'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:390:in `block in run_examples'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:386:in `map'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:386:in `run_examples'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:371:in `run'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `block in run'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `map'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `run'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in run'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `map'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block in run'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:58:in `report'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:25:in `run'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/test_framework/rspec.rb:11:in `run_tests'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:13:in `block in run'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/forker.rb:21:in `block in initialize'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `fork'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `initialize'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `new'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `run'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/server.rb:48:in `run'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1548:in `perform_without_block'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1508:in `perform'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1586:in `block (2 levels) in main_loop'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1582:in `loop'
 # /home/fletch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1582:in `block in main_loop'
```

Answer (score 0):

Forehead slap. We're stubbing `File.open` in our specs.